# Insights won't launch, just buffers

Tags: accessibility-insights

I have used this extension since it was launched, and it's my favorite. Now when I click the icon, it continually buffers, and never launches.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the extension.
I have turned off all other extensions in case there was a conflict. No difference.
Anyone else have this problem, and what is the solution?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

We (the Accessibility Insights team) are investigating this as a bug tracked by [microsoft/accessibility-insights-web issue #6524](https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-web/issues/6524). Please refer to that issue for updates and for instructions on how you can share debugging information that may help us identify and fix the issue.